# AngularJS + Django - csrf for separate apps

Tags: django, angularjs

I have both a Django app and a Angular JS app hosted at different end-points. Obviously in order for XHR requests to work I need to set the csrf token within Angular, which is easy enough to do when Angular is served by Django, but not so much when independent.

Here is my code so far:

```
angular.module('App', [
    'ngCookies',
])
.run(['$rootScope', '$http', '$cookies', 
    function($rootScope, $http, $cookies){
        // Set the CSRF header token to match Django
        $http.defaults.headers.post['X-CSRFToken'] = $cookies['csrftoken'];

        // Bootstrap
        $http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/test/').success(function(resp){
            console.log($cookies['csrftoken']);
        });
    }
])
```

It seems that $cookies['csrftoken'] is always undefined, and I assume I have to retrieve this somehow but can't find any resources as to how this process works.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: maybe you're missing `@csrf_exempt` in the django view that receives the request? I do something similar and I didn't have to modify the headers

Comment: I don't want to csrf_exempt my API. It has to be relatively secure unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cookies are only accessible on the same origin, so accessing from another domain won't share the CSRF Token through cookies, you're going to have to find another way to introduce the cookie (such as with Django's template tag).

Second, your example looks likes its trying to read a Cookie from the `$http.get()` call.  The `$cookie` service collects Cookies from when the document is loaded (stored `document.cookie`) and the resulting cookies are not accessible from Ajax/XHR calls cross-domain.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
app = angular.module("App", []);

app.run(function($http) {
    $http.defaults.headers.post['X-CSRFToken'] = $.cookie('csrftoken');
});
```

where `$.cookie` comes from [jQuery Cookie plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/).